# How can I implement Named Service with parameters in Autofac?

Tags: c#, autofac

I've a concrete Service and it's behaviour differs by it's parameters, I could not achieve to Register and Resolve it by Autofac. As you can see it is so easy to implement it by custom Container.  How can I use Autofac for this requirement?

```
public class Container
{
    Dictionary<string, MyService> _components = new Dictionary<string, MyService>();

    void Register(string key,string param, string param2)
    {
        _components.Add(key, new MyService(param, param2, ResolveRepository()));
    }

    MyService ResolveMyService(string key)
    {
        return _components[key];
    }

    IRepository ResolveRepository()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class MyService
{
    public MyService(string param,string param2,IRepository rep ) { }
}

public interface IRepository   {    }
```

EDIT: I'm trying the solve registration in Autofac, but we have no Container during Registration process.

```
builder.RegisterType<MyService>()
       .Named<MyService>("Service1")
       .OnActivating(e =>
       {
           e.ReplaceInstance(new MyService("Service1", "param1-23", Container.Resolve<IRepository>()));
       });
```

Comment: It's not clear of what you are trying to do.Could you show us How you tried to register your service in Autofac and how you expect it to be resolved ?

Comment: I've Added sample code for autofac,  Container.Resolve<IRepository>() part of code is problematic, because we have no Container during build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the container during the `Activating` pseudo event by using `e.Context`

```
builder.RegisterType<MyService>()
       .Named<MyService>("Service1")
       .OnActivating(e =>
       {
           MyService s = new MyService("Service1", 
                                       "param1-23",
                                       e.Context.Resolve<IRepository>())
           e.ReplaceInstance();
       });
```

but another option would be to use the `WithParameter` method.

```
builder.RegisterType<MyService>()
       .Named<MyService>("Service1")
       .WithParameter("param1", "Service1")
       .WithParameter("param2", "param1-23");
```